# Translate Oracle Regular Expression Query to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, regex, oracle, regexp-like

Hello I need to translate this query from an Oracle Database to MSSQL and get the exact same result:

`WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(E.EVENTS, 'selfServe:[^:]*:completed[:]')`.

My following attempts have all failed:

`WHEN EVENTS LIKE '%[:]selfServe[:][^:]%[:]completed[:]%'`

`EVENTS LIKE '%[:]selfServe[:]%[^:][:]completed[:]%'`

`WHERE PATINDEX('selfServe:[^:]*:completed[:]', EVENTS) != 0`

`WHERE PATINDEX('selfServe:[^:]%:completed[:]', EVENTS) != 0` .

Examples:

This should not match:

```
OpenQ,
Payment,
Payment:selfServe:Payment-Cancel_Scheduled:initiated::,
Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,
Payment:authentication:Authentication:completed::,
HUP
```

While this should match:

```
OpenQ2,
Payment,
Payment:selfServe:Payment:initiated::,
Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,
Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,
Payment:authentication:Authentication:completed::,
Payment:selfServe:Payment:completed::,
HUP
```

In the first case I have `authentication:completed` but not `selfServe:Payment:completed`.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't really have regex support.  Can you provide some data examples of what would match and what wouldn't?

Comment: Here it should not match
`OpenQ,Payment,Payment:selfServe:Payment-Cancel_Scheduled:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:completed::,HUP`
while here it should match:
`OpenQ2,Payment,Payment:selfServe:Payment:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:completed::,Payment:selfServe:Payment:completed::,HUP`
In the first case I have `authentication:completed`

Comment: As is, your question can be answered by people that are familiar with both Oracle regular expressions and SQL Server's T-SQL. In order to improve your changes to get a good answer as soon as possible, I would forget the Oracle part and instead focus on the SQL Server part. Sample data as DDL+DML (create table and insert statements) and expected results should get you an accurate answer pretty fast.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I want to run this query using a BI tool, so I need to avoid DDL+DML

Comment: The DDL+DML of sample data is not for you, it's for us to copy and paste into a test environment so that we can run whatever query we come up with and make sure it produce the desired results before posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would tackle this with a string splitting function that looks for the appropriate `selfServe:...:completed` within one of the comma delimited strings.  If you are using a fairly modern version of SQL Server, you may be able to do this using the built in `string_split` function:

## string_split

```
declare @t table(id int,t varchar(1000));
insert into @t values
 (1,'OpenQ,Payment,Payment:selfServe:Payment-Cancel_Scheduled:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:completed::,HUP')
,(2,'OpenQ2,Payment,Payment:selfServe:Payment:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:completed::,Payment:selfServe:Payment:completed::,HUP');


select t.id
      ,s.value
      ,t.t
from @t as t
    cross apply string_split(t.t,',') as s
where case when patindex('%:selfServe:%',s.value) > 0
                and patindex('%:completed:%',s.value) > 0
            then 1
            else 0
            end = 1;
```

## Output

```
+----+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |                 value                 |                                                                                                                          t                                                                                                                           |
+----+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | Payment:selfServe:Payment:completed:: | OpenQ2,Payment,Payment:selfServe:Payment:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:completed::,Payment:selfServe:Payment:completed::,HUP |
+----+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

If not, you will need to roll your own string splitter.  I am going to assume that you may have some fairly long strings here (more than 4000 characters) and am therefore using an `XML` based splitter that works well with `max` data types.

As you are doing this within a BI tool that I am assuming will not allow you to make a new Table Valued Function within the database, you will need a fairly complex statement to process your data, that incorporates the string splitter inline:

## Roll your own

```
declare @t table(id int,t varchar(1000));
insert into @t values
 (1,'OpenQ,Payment,Payment:selfServe:Payment-Cancel_Scheduled:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:completed::,HUP')
,(2,'OpenQ2,Payment,Payment:selfServe:Payment:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:completed::,Payment:selfServe:Payment:completed::,HUP');

with s as
(       -- Convert the string to an XML value, replacing the delimiter with XML tags
    select id
          ,t
          ,convert(xml,'<x>' + replace((select '' + t for xml path('')),',','</x><x>') + '</x>').query('.') as s
    from @t
)
select id
        ,item
        ,t     -- Select the values from the generated XML value by CROSS APPLYing to the XML nodes
from(select id
            ,t
            ,n.x.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as item
    from s
            cross apply s.nodes('x') as n(x)
    ) a
where case when patindex('%:selfServe:%',a.item) > 0
                and patindex('%:completed:%',a.item) > 0
            then 1
            else 0
            end = 1;
```

## Output

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |                  item                   |                                                                                                                          t                                                                                                                           |
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 |   Payment:selfServe:Payment:completed:: | OpenQ2,Payment,Payment:selfServe:Payment:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:initiated::,Payment:authentication:Authentication:completed::,Payment:selfServe:Payment:completed::,HUP |
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```